# Korg as MIDI + Send Kontakt sound to Korg Kronos

Tags: midi, korg

I am using Kontakt 6 standalone with The GIANT piano library. I cannot figure out how to:

1. Correctly configure Kronos so that it does not play its own sounds but works as a simple keyboard, playing sounds from Kontakt. It is running on my Windows notebook.
2. Have Kontakt send the played sound back to Kronos so that I can hear the melody using my headphones plugged into Kronos and not the notebook speakers.

More information:

I have installed the drivers so Kronos is showing up in Kontakt. When I press a key, it is showing up on the on-screen mini "piano". I even figured out how to output the sound to the speaker jack on the notebook.

I silenced the Korg melody by simply muting the channel with a musical instrument with an ordinary init program but that is probably not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem. Now I can listen to Kontakt audio coming through the MIDI cable from my notebook while playing Kronos. Here's how (by the way, this information is *impossible! to! find!* on the internet.

KONTAKT:

- Audio -> Output: set to KRONOS; Driver: Wasapi shared mode

Channel where the instrument in the main UI is being outputted needs to be set in Channels dialogue (shortcut F2) to

- O1 -> 1-Headphones L, O2 -> Headphones R

KRONOS side:

- a new program must be created
- in the edit program mode, click on `Audio In/Sampling` tab, set `Bus select IFX/Indiv` in columns `USB1` and `USB2` to `L/R` so both stereo channels coming from Kontakt via MIDI cable are mapped. I had to set both USBs to L/R, otherwise I'd hear only one speaker of my headphones :)
- within the program, disable the instrumend which would be otherwise played by the KRONOS itself - various ways to do that, pick your preferred one.

Answer (score 1):

The original is very useful but I still had to spend a few more hours to figure out the rest, so I'd like to share the complete solution here. This answer is for a MacBook Pro running MacOS Big Sur and KRONOS 2. There is no additional driver required.

***KONTAKT 6***

Go to Settings, click on the Audio tab.

- Driver: Core
- Audio Device: KRONOS_USB_L&R

Click on the Midi tab. Choose Inputs subtab.

- KRONOS (KEYBOARD): Port A
- Kontakt Virtual Input: Off

***KRONOS 2***

Press PROG button. Press the first ">" on top-left next to the patch name for "Bank/Program Select". For me, I chose U-G008 which is part of the USER-G group of patches. Press OK.

You should be in the "Play" tab. Press and select the "Audio In/Sampling" subtab. Now uncheck the "Use Global Setting". This will enable you to change both of the USB 1 and USB 2 column to "L/R" for the "Bus Select (IFX/Indiv) row only.

Next, press the "OSC/Pitch" tab (2 down from the Play tab), and the "OSC 1 Basic" subtab. In the Multisample/Wave sequence column, set everything i.e. 1-8 to "Off". This basically turns off all instruments because what we want is for the KONTAKT sample to come through and not the KRONOS sound.

Don't forget to save this program by clicking the top right down arrow, then select "Write Program".

***Bonus***

The next thing you want after discovered this great feature, next thing is how to switch instruments via the Kronos keyboard. In other words, you don't want to go back to the MacBook to switch to a different instrument. Wouldn't it be great to be able to switch your Kontakt instruments via the Kronos keyboard? Here is how.

On the above, if you are able to create U-G008 (and tested that it works), go make U-G001 to U-G007 the same. Named the patches as "Kontakt" would be fine.

On the Kontakt side:

- click on the disk icon, in the drop down choose "New Instrument Bank"
- Next, click on the "spanner" icon on the top left and you should see a table of slots 000 to 128.
- In each slot, you can drag an instrument from the Library window from the left. In our example, you can do 8 instruments i.e. U-G001 to U-G008. So drag 8 instruments into 000 to 007.
- On the Kronos, go to program U-G001. On the Kontakt, click on instrument 000 that you assigned.
- Now all you have to do is on the Kronos either use the ^ or V to change program, or the wheel. As you do that, you will see the Kontakt instrument bank also move forward or backward. And you will notice the instrument is changed, playing through the Kronos L/R.

Comment: Thanks @dpoon2000 for your additional info. Can't wait to try it out!